# break row into rows and columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet, row1 contains columns in certain order, 
i want to break this row at a specific cell contains chart[*], into multi rows.
[image of the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipu7Z.png),

or if there is a macro that count  number of cells then copy them into new row will do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

In cell **A9** enter:

```
=IF(OFFSET($A$1,0,COLUMN()-1+6*(ROWS($1:1)-1))="","",OFFSET($A$1,0,COLUMN()-1+6*(ROWS($1:1)-1)))
```

and then copy both across and downward.